# Непонятен результат выполнения кода

Tags: php

Почему при выполнению данного скрипта в результате также выводится "e", но не выводится "d"

```
$x = 1;
if ($x == '1') {
  echo 'a';
}
if ($x == true) {
  echo 'b';
}
if((bool)$x === true){
  echo 'e';
}
if((int)$x === true){
  echo 'd';
}
```

Comment: А почему d должно выводится ? числовой тип данных int никак не может быть тождественен логическому (булеву) типу (true).

Comment: Ну смотри (bool) - это привeдение к логическому типу, и поэтому выводит "e". "d" не выводит поскольку мы сравниваем $x как переменную целочисленного типа с true

Comment: аааааааа...понял! точно ж..спасибо Вам ребята!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что операция `===` сравнивает не только значение операндов, но и их тип.

Если `$x=1`, то `(bool)$x` приводится к типу `bool` и значению `true`

`(bool)$x === true` - это сравнение даст `true`, так как совпадают и значение и тип

`(int)$x === true` - тут `$x` приводится к целому числу (`int`), а сравнивается с типом `bool`. Соответственно, хотя по значению они оба считаются за `true`, но тип у них при этом остается разный, поэтому сравнение возвращает `false`